# Problem defining the insert method of a list in z3

Tags: z3, smt

I am developing a insert method in Z3 for a list. But, I have to meet some requirements:

- The item is not inserted,if it is already in the list
- the item is not inserted,if the list (the set) is full

  First of all, I define the datatype:

`(declare-datatypes (T) ((Lst nil (cons (hd T) (tl Lst)))))`

I define the functions isFull to know if the list maximum capacity exceeded and IsMember to know if the list contains a number.

```
(define-fun isFull  ((l (Lst Int))) Bool
  (ite
    (<= (len l) 10)
    false
    true
  )
)
(define-fun-rec isMember((i Int) (l (Lst Int))) Bool 
  (ite
    (= l nil)
    false
    (or (= i (hd l)) (isMember i (tl l)))
  )
)
```

Then I tried to define a insert method but something is wrong:

```
(define-fun insert ((i Int) (l (Lst Int))) (l (Lst Int))
  (ite (= false (isMember i l )  )
    (ite (= false (isFull l ))
      (ite(= l nil)
          (= (hd l) i)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us your definition of `len`, and there are a bunch of syntactic errors in your code. But you seem to be on the right track. I'd code your spec as follows:

```lisp
(declare-datatypes (T) ((Lst nil (cons (hd T) (tl Lst)))))

(define-fun-rec len ((l (Lst Int))) Int
   (ite (= l nil) 0 (+ 1 (len (tl l)))))

(define-fun isFull  ((l (Lst Int))) Bool
  (> (len l) 10))

(define-fun-rec isMember ((i Int) (l (Lst Int))) Bool
  (and (distinct l nil)
       (or (= i (hd l))
           (isMember i (tl l)))))

(define-fun funnyInsert ((i Int) (l (Lst Int))) (Lst Int)
  (ite (or (isMember i l) (isFull l))
       l
       (cons i l)))
```

I've called your insert `funnyInsert`, since what it does is rather funny.

Note that while z3 will accept this program as is, it's unlikely you can prove anything interesting with these definitions. Properties of recursive functions are usually proven using induction, and SMT-solvers generally don't perform induction. At least not out-of-the box without a lot of tinkering with tactics and such. Best of luck!